# django aggregate and filter

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm going to convert this sql to django commands:

```
SELECT
  core.id,
  core.title,
  core.age_id,
  core.cat_id,
  max(date) AS max_date
FROM core
WHERE core.state = 'ABC'
GROUP BY cat_id, age_id
```

I tried this, but not works correctly:

```
Core.objects.values('id', 'title', 'age_id', 'cat_id').filter(state='ABC').annotate(
            max_date=Max('date')).aggregate(Count('age_id', 'cat_id'))
```

Comment: Why are you using aggregate?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this with [values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#values) but restrict fields that you want to group by

```
Core.objects.values('age_id', 'cat_id').filter(state='ABC').annotate(Max('date'), Count('age_id', 'cat_id'))
```

Comment: I have compile error in `Count('age_id', 'cat_id')`

Comment: `Positional argument after keyword argument`

Comment: Edited answer, try that

Comment: I need `id` and `title` columns too.

Comment: That is syntaz for generatinf query you wanted. About result, 1. explain more what you trying to do? 2. What is the result you are expecting?

Comment: The result of my row sql and your solution result is not the same.
you solution has huge number of rows.